# Calculate average annual inflation

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, inflation, nonexpert

The price index in the year 1993 is 60.

The base at 2012 is 100.

The annual nominal interest rate between 1993 and 2012 is 66% on average.

What is the average annual inflation between 1993 and 2012?

I know that

Inflation = $\frac{X_{t+s}-X_t}{X_t}$x$ 100$

where $X_{t+s}$ is the current year and $X_t$ is the year being compared.

However, when I use this formula with $X_{t+s}=100$ (since it is the base of the index) and $X_t=60$, I just get the annual nominal interest rate of 66.6666%.

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The calculation goes like:

Price index @ 1993 =  60 $ \Rightarrow X_{t+s}=0.6  $

Price index @ 2012 = 100 $ \Rightarrow X_{t}=1$

Number of years from 1993 to 2012: $ 2012 -1993 = 19 \Rightarrow s=19$

$100*((\frac{X_{t+s}}{X_t})^{(\frac{1}{s})}-1) = 100*(\frac{1}{0.6} ^{(1/19)}-1)=100*(\sqrt[19]{(5/3)}-1)=2.72502$

Comment: You may want to add that you use the *geometric average* here, because the price levels is obtained by compounding of the inflation rates over time.